# Whole home folder under git repo

Tags: git

Recently installed oh-my-zsh. i noticed that in all my folders under home  directory there was a master from git plug in appearing.

```
    On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .AndroidStudio2.1/
    .CFUserTextEncoding
    .DS_Store
    .PyCharm40/
    .Xauthority
    .android/
    .atom/
    ...(list of all my folders)
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Should i git ignore my home folder? Any ideas?

Comment: So, what do you want exactly, any example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a .git folder inside my ~ directory and everything under it was mentioned as git repository. after deleting it the (master) word from git plug in dissapeared